# Find the angle in the given figure

Tags: geometry, angle

Is question is a physics problem related to surface tension, but that isn’t relevant here. [image]

Angle $CDB=\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and the angle $\theta$ are where they are as shown in the figure.

How is angle $ABC=\theta +\frac{\alpha}{2}$?

I couldn’t find any relation between those two, but that obtaining that result is imperative for solving this. How are they related?

Comment: Extend the tangent (which makes an angle $\theta$ with $BD$) at the surface of liquid which intersects $CD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Extend the ray of $\theta$ from B to intersect AD at E. Triangles ABE and ABC are similar because they are ridght angle and have a common angle $\angle  BAD$. Therefore $\angle BEA=\angle ABC$.But  $\angle BEA=\theta +\frac {\alpha}2$ because it is external angle of triangle BDE. Therefore :

$\angle ABC=\angle BEA=\theta +\frac {\alpha}2$

Answer (score 0):

Say the tangent to the liquid interface from $B$ meets $AD$ at $P$. Then considering the exterior angle of $\triangle BPD$, $$\angle BPC=\theta+\frac{\alpha}{2} \\ \implies \angle PBC=\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(\theta+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \\ \implies \angle ABC=\theta +\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Comment: Can I randomly ask for clarification: how do you get from the second last step to the last step? Is $PBA$ a right triangle? It isn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: @Kman3 I’ve assumed that the circular arc has its center at $A$, if that makes things clearer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks (geometry is not my strong suit!)

Comment: The circular arc is supposed to be the top of a cone, so point is vertically above the circle, so can it be the centre?

Comment: @Aditya It must be the centre, otherwise angle $ABC$ would be something other else.

Comment: If I give u the original question, would it help? I didn’t want include it since it’s physics

Comment: @Aditya I don’t see why not?

Comment: If $Cos(\tetta +\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{b} R$ is known, then in right triagle ABC we have $Cos (\angle ABC=\frac{b}R$, so $\angle ABC=\tetta+\frac{\alpha} 2$.

Comment: @sirous It is not already known, which is why Aditya has asked this question.